# How to enable Privileged Identity Management(PIM) for Storage blob data reader role in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I have a Azure storage account and in that there are multiple containers. I need to give access to particular container using security group ( /via access package).

Considering least privileged access in Azure, how can I enable giving access to my Data storage/container ( for example, blob) so that users can PIM up before accessing a specific container ( e.g. Blob) from Azure?

The roles that needs to go via Privileged Identity Management(PIM)  could be:

```
 Storage  blob data reader
 Storage blob date contributor
```

I was going via MS tutorials here( [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory), [Link3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-assign-roles) ). However, unable to figure out the right and best approach for this. Is there any other step by step guide? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start with you can ,[use the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) itself for the `Storage Blob Data Contributor ,Storage Blob Data Owner`  where [Azure role assignment condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-overview) can be done as an additional check that you can optionally add to your role assignment to provide more ***`fine-grained access control`***.

[Add or edit Azure role assignment conditions :**PORTAL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-role-assignments-portal) which is preview account.

> and yes the scope can be container level.

Click **Add condition**  to further refine the role assignments based on storage attributes.

[image]

You can then add resource and conditions like ex: Ifselected user tries to read a blob without the Project=Cascade tag, access will not be allowed.

[image]

•   **Resource** indicates that the attribute is on the resource, such as `container name.` You have to type the name and drop down wont be listed to select the blob.

This can be done from `ARM template` also.
The following template shows how to assign the Storage Blob Data Reader role with a condition. The condition checks whether the container name equals 'blobs-example-container' which can be given with resource ***`@Resource[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers:name] StringEquals 'blobs-example-container'`***

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Principal ID to assign the role to"
            }
        },
        "principalType": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Type of principal"
            }
        },
        "roleAssignmentGuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "New GUID used to identify the role assignment"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "StorageBlobDataReader": "[concat(subscription().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')]" // ID for Storage Blob Data Reader role, but can be any valid role ID
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('roleAssignmentGuid')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview", // API version to call the role assignment PUT.
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('StorageBlobDataReader')]",
                "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
                "principalType": "[parameters('principalType')]",
                "description": "Role assignment condition created with an ARM template",
                "condition": "((!(ActionMatches{'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read'})) OR (@Resource[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers:name] StringEquals 'blobs-example-container'))", // Role assignment condition
                "conditionVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But additionally  to secureand limit user with a `time-bound setting, approval workflow, audit trail, and so on` along with fine-grained conditions you may need to use PIM and add additional properties like scheduleInfo, admin access
just like the one you have linked to  here using portal or ARM [pim-resource-roles-assign-roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-resource-roles-assign-roles)

```
{
  "properties": {
    "principalId": "a3bb8764-cb92-4276-9d2a-ca1e895e55ea",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/dfa2a084-766f-4003-8ae1-c4aeb893a99f/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/c8d4ff99-41c3-41a8-9f60-21dfdad59608",

    "requestType": "AdminAssign",
    "scheduleInfo": {
      "startDateTime": "2022-07-05T21:00:00.91Z",
      "expiration": {
        "type": "AfterDuration",
        "endDateTime": null,
        "duration": "P365D"
      }
    },
    "condition": "@Resource[Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers:ContainerName] StringEqualsIgnoreCase 'foo_storage_container'",
    "conditionVersion": "1.0"
  }
}
```

See [Schedule Requests](https://What%20is%20Azure%20attribute-based%20access%20control%20(Azure%20ABAC)?%20(preview)%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs%20Role%20Eligibility%20Schedule%20Requests%20-%20Create%20-%20REST%20API%20(Azure%20Authorization)%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs)

You can check the syntax formats [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-format)

You can also make use of [storage-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) for container level access control where you can set expiry time and invoke permissions for those s=resources.

Reference:[Azure attribute-based access control (Azure ABAC)](https://What%20is%20Azure%20attribute-based%20access%20control%20(Azure%20ABAC)?%20(preview)%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs)

Comment: Thanks. However, I tried this. But, instead of giving access to a particular container in storage account. It's giving access to all the containers. I believe the key value is just an example in MSFT document. My question is, what should I keep in Key and value box? From where can I get those attribute to fill in ? Please suggest.